# how can i get runnig application package name in service in android?

Tags: android, service, android-service

hello Im new in android developement,I tried search and I didnt get my answer  ,I wanna get all open application package name in service and check them with my database, I tried this code and didnt work ,I want get runnig app package name in the past and future ,so I want try this with services...

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.rasamohtava.access;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.usage.UsageStats;
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class CheckAppLaunchThread extends Thread {
    private Context context;
    private Handler handler;
    private ActivityManager actMan;
    private int timer = 100;
    public static final String TAG = "App Thread";
    public static String lastUnlocked;

// private String lastUnlocked;

    public CheckAppLaunchThread(Handler mainHandler, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.handler = mainHandler;
        actMan = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        this.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, AppLockService.class));
        Looper.prepare();
        String prevTasks;
        String recentTasks = "";

        prevTasks = recentTasks;
        Log.d("Thread", "Inside Thread");
        while (true) {
            try {
                String topPackageName = "";
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

                    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    // We get usage stats for the last 10 seconds
                    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*5, time);
                    if(stats != null) {
                        SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
                        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);
                        }
                        if(mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                            topPackageName =  mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    topPackageName = actMan.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
                }
                recentTasks = topPackageName;
                Thread.sleep(timer);
                if (recentTasks.length()==0 || recentTasks.equals(prevTasks)) {

                }
                else {
                    if (isAppLocked(recentTasks)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Locked miladk313" + recentTasks);
                        handler.post(new RequestPassword(context, recentTasks));
                    }
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            prevTasks = recentTasks;

        }

    }

    class ToastRunnable implements Runnable {

        String message;

        public ToastRunnable(String text) {
            message = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    class RequestPassword implements Runnable {

        private Context mContext;
        private String pkgName;

        public RequestPassword(Context mContext, String pkgName) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.pkgName = pkgName;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent passwordAct = new Intent(context, BlockActivity.class);
            passwordAct.putExtra("PACKAGE_NAME", pkgName);
            passwordAct.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            this.mContext.startActivity(passwordAct);

        }

    }

    private boolean isAppLocked(String packageName) {
        if (packageName.equals(BlockActivity.lastUnlocked)) {
            return false;
        }
        BlockActivity.lastUnlocked = null;
        DatabaseManager dbHelper = new DatabaseManager(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_blacklist WHERE package_name=\'"
                + packageName + "\'", null);
        boolean isLocked = false;
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            isLocked = true;
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        dbHelper.close();
        return isLocked;
    }
}
```